# Weird behaviour in vhdl average using Microsemi FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Good Afternoon, I am working on some code of averaging with a sliding window using VHDL language.
The problem is that the accumulator takes sometimes wrong values. (generally after restart)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;



entity cc_rssi_avr is 
  port ( 
        nrst         : in std_logic;
        clk         : in std_logic; --
        ena        : in std_logic;
        data_in     : in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        data_out    : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
   );
end cc_rssi_avr;

architecture rtl of cc_rssi_avr is 

constant buffer_size : natural :=8;

type MEM is array(0 to buffer_size-1) of std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);

signal shift_LT : MEM:=(others =>(others=>'0'));
signal sum_val:std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);

begin 
  --shift input data at every clock edge
   process(clk,nrst)
    begin 
  if nrst='0' then 
     shift_LT <= (others => (others => '0'));
     sum_val <= (others=>'0');

  elsif clk'event and clk='1' then

    if ena = '0' then 
      shift_LT<=(others=>(others=>'0'));
      sum_val<=(others=>'0');
    else 
      shift_LT(0) <= data_in;
      shift_LT(1 to buffer_size-1) <= shift_LT(0 to buffer_size-2);

      sum_val <= sum_val + ("000"&data_in) - ("000"&shift_LT(buffer_size-1));

    end if;

  end if;
end process;

   data_out<=sum_val(sum_val'high downto 3);

end rtl;
```

The problem is somehow, sum_val adds a value without subtraction or subtracts without addition, in a way that if the input returns to 0, the output returns to 7850 or a random value but not zero.

The design is running @ 20 MHz (FPGA : Microsemi Smartfusion M2S050), and consists on an ADC driven by FPGA clock, and its output is routed to the FPGA pins so the samples are processed with this module in order to compute the average on 8 samples.

One last information that might be useful : FPGA is 92.6% Occupied (4LUT).

Can anyone provide some help.
Thanks

Comment: Problem is that MEM type you declared which most likely causes these issues. Adding vectors should not work like you did but creating array may mask that. As I cannot test it now but I suggest you replace that MEM type with simple types.

Comment: Have you got your problem in simulation ? Or only on card ?

Comment: @Myszsoda thanks for the suggestion, I will tried.

Comment: @Gautitho the problem is only on card. simulation works as expected !

Comment: Is data_in properly synchronised to clk? does the design meet timing requirements?

Comment: @Tricky clock is generated with FPGA, and routed to an ADC, which "CLK Rise to Output Data Valid 8 ns max". The path length between FPGA and ADC is 25 mm x 2 => 50 millimeters. 
Before answering, I was thinking that data_in is properly synchronised to clk.
But now you made me think about the issue, and data_in to shift_LT(0) must be constrained !

Comment: Not only that, it needs to be properly synchyronised across the clock domain by at least a double register to prevent meta-stability and reading incorrect values. Ideally you would put the data through a FIFO (as this is safer than simply a double register). Also, how is clk generated in FPGA? logic generated clocks are not recommended to clock anything on-chip.

Comment: Clock is generated using a PLL in FPGA. But why cross domain synchronization or FIFO, when I am using a single clock domain ?